# Convert not selected checkboxes row in html table to javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’ve got a HTML table and for each row I’ve got a checkbox, some cells with text and a cell with a input field, I need to convert all the rows except the one selcted into a javascript array so I can then pass the array to ajax and process with PHP.

This is what i've tried so far

```js
var TableData = new Array();

$('.kmg_admin_millesimal_buildings_table tr input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').each(function(row, tr) {

  TableData[row] = {

    "Codice": $(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text(),
    "Piano": $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text(),
    "Interno": $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text(),
    "Millesimi": $(tr).find('td').eq(4).find('input').val()

  }

});

TableData.shift();
TableData.pop();

console.log(TableData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="kmg_admin_millesimal_buildings_table">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="text-center"> Escludi</th>
    <th class="text-center"> Codice</th>
    <th class="text-center"> Piano</th>
    <th class="text-center"> Interno</th>
    <th> Millesimi</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="kmg_admin_millesimal_buildings_table_body">
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="pippo"></td>
    <td class="text-center">4E</td>
    <td class="text-center">1</td>
    <td class="text-center">4E</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="km-millesimi" maxlength="6"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="pippo"></td>
    <td class="text-center">9N</td>
    <td class="text-center">2</td>
    <td class="text-center">9N</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="km-millesimi" maxlength="6"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="pippo"></td>
    <td class="text-center">2C</td>
    <td class="text-center">3</td>
    <td class="text-center">2C</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="km-millesimi" maxlength="6"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot class="custom-table-footer">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" class="text-right"></td>
    <td class="km_total_millesimal_table font-green-sharp">0.00</td>
  </tr>
</tfoot>
<table>
```

The error is that the array is not created

Comment: instead of posting an image of your table, it would be helpful if you would just post the code, that way people who want to test your code don't have to write all the markup to generate it.

Comment: also, you need to tell us what the problem is.

Comment: you have two rows that are unchecked. after you `pop()` it you have one row. then you `shift()` it and now you have an empty array. that's probably the problem.

Comment: Hi @Iwrestledabearonce. I've updated the question

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. if I remove pop() and shift() I get the following (2) […]

0: Object { Codice: "", Piano: "", Interno: "", … }

1: Object { Codice: "", Piano: "", Interno: "", … }
length: 2

Comment: Thank you. Although that doesn't really help with the markup, you could use devtools to get the outerHTML of the generated table and post the markup, we don't don't need the javascript that created the table. Anyway, did you try removing the pop() and shift() like I suggested above?

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. yes I wrote the console result in the comments and I've added the html code for the table

Comment: thanks for making those adjustments, @pippo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your selector is targetting inputs, not table rows. you can use `parent()` to get the row, like this. You still need to remove the shift() and the pop() too, since there are no inputs in the thead and tfoot these are not needed.

```js
var TableData = new Array();

$('.kmg_admin_millesimal_buildings_table tr input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').each(function(row, input) {
  var tr = $(input).parent().parent()
  TableData[row] = {

    "Codice": $(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text(),
    "Piano": $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text(),
    "Interno": $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text(),
    "Millesimi": $(tr).find('td').eq(4).find('input').val()

  }

});

console.log(TableData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="kmg_admin_millesimal_buildings_table">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="text-center"> Escludi</th>
    <th class="text-center"> Codice</th>
    <th class="text-center"> Piano</th>
    <th class="text-center"> Interno</th>
    <th> Millesimi</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="kmg_admin_millesimal_buildings_table_body">
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="pippo"></td>
    <td class="text-center">4E</td>
    <td class="text-center">1</td>
    <td class="text-center">4E</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="km-millesimi" maxlength="6"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="pippo"></td>
    <td class="text-center">9N</td>
    <td class="text-center">2</td>
    <td class="text-center">9N</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="km-millesimi" maxlength="6"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="pippo"></td>
    <td class="text-center">2C</td>
    <td class="text-center">3</td>
    <td class="text-center">2C</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="km-millesimi" maxlength="6"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot class="custom-table-footer">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" class="text-right"></td>
    <td class="km_total_millesimal_table font-green-sharp">0.00</td>
  </tr>
</tfoot>
<table>
```

Comment: Many thanks it works fine. Sorry I'm still not good at recognising the selectors in javascript. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I'd use vanilla Javascript, as always. Here you go:

```js
var TableData = new Array();

foo.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  // only react if the change came from a checkbox
  if (e.target.matches('input.pippo')) {
    TableData = [...foo.querySelectorAll('.kmg_admin_millesimal_buildings_table tr input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)')]
      .map(input => {
        let res = [...input.closest('tr').cells].map(cell => (cell.textContent || cell.children[0].value));
        return { codice: res[1], piano: res[2], interno: res[3], millesimi: res[4] };
      })
    console.clear();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(TableData));
  }
})
```

```html
<table class="kmg_admin_millesimal_buildings_table" id="foo">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="text-center"> Escludi</th>
    <th class="text-center"> Codice</th>
    <th class="text-center"> Piano</th>
    <th class="text-center"> Interno</th>
    <th> Millesimi</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="kmg_admin_millesimal_buildings_table_body">
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="pippo"></td>
    <td class="text-center">4E</td>
    <td class="text-center">1</td>
    <td class="text-center">4E</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="km-millesimi" maxlength="6"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="pippo"></td>
    <td class="text-center">9N</td>
    <td class="text-center">2</td>
    <td class="text-center">9N</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="km-millesimi" maxlength="6"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="pippo"></td>
    <td class="text-center">2C</td>
    <td class="text-center">3</td>
    <td class="text-center">2C</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="km-millesimi" maxlength="6"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot class="custom-table-footer">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" class="text-right"></td>
    <td class="km_total_millesimal_table font-green-sharp">0.00</td>
  </tr>
</tfoot>
<table>
```